# How to change color based on Dark or Light Theme - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my app I have a light theme and a dark theme.
I'm trying to style a custom component, so that a color will depend on whether it's a dark theme or light theme. This is my code in the custom component scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin app-toolbar-theme($theme) {
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $warn: map-get($theme, warn);

    .mat-toolbar {
        background: //if dark theme 'red', if light theme 'blue'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change the background of the toolbar based on whether I'm in a dark or light theme?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this.
I create two mixin component themes, and add the light one to the light theme, and the dark to the dark theme.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin app-toolbar-light-theme($theme) {
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);

    .skill-toolbar {
        background-color: mat-color($accent);
    }
}

@mixin app-toolbar-dark-theme($theme) {
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);

    .skill-toolbar {
        background-color: mat-color($primary, 400);
    }
}
```

And in my styles.scss:

```
@import "app/...../toolbar.component.scss-theme.scss";

@mixin custom-components-light-theme($theme) {
  @include app-toolbar-light-theme($theme);
}

@mixin custom-components-dark-theme($theme) {
  @include app-toolbar-dark-theme($theme);
}

.my-light-theme {
 @include angular-material-theme($my-light-theme);
  @include custom-components-light-theme($my-light-theme);
}

.my-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-dark-theme);
  @include custom-components-dark-theme($my-dark-theme);
}
```